# How to follow Hindu Funeral Ritual in USA with following constraints

Tags: funeral

How to follow Hindu Funeral Ritual in USA with following constraints

I am female, and only child of my Father. He wants me (not Priest, etc) to light the funeral pyre and he says paying more than $1000 is foolish.

What are the proper rituals to follow so that I can light my Father's funeral pyre (not some priest). What rituals can we for-go to lower the cost.

Again my Dad says paying more than $1000 is foolish, but I'd rather like to spend more if it means following his wishes and the Hindu tradition so he can get Moksha.

Please guide

Comment: I thought the deceased is burned in an open fire. Why in something to impersonal as an oven?

Comment: you are not looking at the soul..Of what matter is the rest?

Comment: If your dad wants moksha then his last breathe has to be in Kashi kshetra. Ofcourse there are other ways to get moksha but I assume your dad has not led a life that prepares one for moksha in final stages.

Comment: If there is any Hindu community nearby, they could definitely help you with it. Rituals are not very hard - if you find a pandit or an astrologer or something, they might help you with it. Om Shanti.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely perform rituals to help his soul leave this world peacefully but you cannot help him attain moksha. Attaining moksha is an individual's effort. There are some ways of attaining moksha. Firstly, someone who renounces materialistic life and becomes a sadhu and spends his life in devotion. Secondly, performs his daily activities selflessly thinking that God is the doer not you which helps you to be free from karmic cycle and performing bhakti by meditating on him, chanting mantra and praying to him. Finally, what you think at the time of death decides your next life. If you remember God at the time of death then you attain him and achieve moksha.

Comment: My Dad has so many worries, he prays he leaves with happiness. I just want to give a dignified and respectful funeral per Hindu traditions and his wishes.